# An error occurred while sending the request with PostAsJsonAsync

Tags: soap, http-post, httprequest

I have a soap web service which is being consumed by an application. This web service when called from the application posts the data it receives by a call to another web service via POST request using "PostAsJsonAsync". Sometimes the call to the other web service goes through but sometimes it throws an error - "An error occurred while sending the request". There is no specific use case or data scenario when this happens. It just happens at random.

The other service uses a token authentication system. The token is getting generated correctly in every case but the call doesn't go through for some.

Could anyone please guide me what might be the root cause for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with certificate validation with request. Resolved by adding this piece of code before making the http post call - `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };`